# Apply Newton's method in the implicit Euler method together with fft

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis

Assume I want to solve the following pde:
$$
p_t= \Delta(p^3) - \Delta^2 p
$$
by using a fully-implicit method, and Fourier transform for the spatial differentiation. The method assumes the following formula (using matlab notation):
$$
p^{n+1}-p^n = dt \left(  - ifft( fft( p^{n+1} *k^4 ) ) + ifft(fft((p^{n+1})^3*k^2)) \right)
$$
where $k$ represents the frequency of $p$, $p^{n}$ represents the value of $p$ at the $n$th time-step, ifft is the inverse fast Fourier transform, and fft is the fast Fourier transform.

My questions are:

1. Is my use of Fourier transform for the nonlinear part $u^3$ is correct?
2. I now have a fully-implicit non-linear equation to solve, and I want to use Newton's method. Therefore, I need to know what is the Jacobian of the equation wrt. $p$. But, how can I calculate the Jacobian of terms like:
   $- ifft( fft( p^{n+1} *k^4 ) )$ ?

Will someone please help me? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ω$ denote the sampling frequency, $2N$ the number of samples so that the space interval resp. period has length $\frac{2\pi}ω$. Then the approximation/representation of the state by trigonometric polynomials is
$$
p(x)=\sum_{k=-N}^{N-1}\hat p_k e^{i·k·\omega x}.
$$
Which gives for the derivatives
$$
p^{(2m)}(x)=\sum_{k=-N}^{N-1}[(-k^2·\omega^2)^m·\hat p_k]· e^{i·k·\omega x}
$$
In view of that you have to use

```
ifft( omega^2*k.^2.*fft(p.^3) + omega^4*k.^4.*fft(p) )
```

Test once if

```
ifft(fft(p))
```

returns exactly `p` or `p` multiplied by its length. In the latter case you have to correct this by dividing by this factor.

---

As to the Newton method, replace $p_+$ by $p_++q$ (where $p=p_n$, $p_+$ is the current approximation of $p_{n+1}$, $q$ is the Newton step, thus $p_++q$ is the improved approximation for $p_{n+1}$) and ignore quadratic or higher order terms in $q$,
$$
p_++q=p + dt·[(p_+^3)''+3(p_+^2q)''-p_+^{(4)}-q^{(4)}]
$$
so that you have to solve the linear differential equation
\begin{multline}
p_+-p-dt·[(p_+^3)''-p_+^{(4)}] \\= f = -q+dt·[3(p_+^2)''·q+6(p_+^2)'·q'+3(p_+^2)·q''-q^{(4)}]
\end{multline}
for $q$ resp. the corresponding linear system with convolutions for the Fourier coefficients of $q$. There does not seem to exist an easy solution.

Comment: What is q? what is $p_+$?? 
Note that I have used $\Delta$ as the laplacian ... so $\Delta^2 $ is the laplacian squared... This is why I have $k^4 . $ THanks !

Comment: $p=p_n$, $p_+$ is the current approximation of $p_{n+1}$, $q$ is the Newton step, thus $p_++q$ is the improved approximation for $p_{n+1}$. -- I assumed from your code that $x$ and thus the space component is one-dimensional Then $Δp=p''$. -- I'm sorry, I did only see what I expected to see in the formula. Still, the correct place for the multiplication with $k^2$ etc. is with `fft(p^3)`, and you need to include the sampling frequency $\omega$.

Comment: Thanks, so actually, when I am in 2D, I have no chance of doing a "simple" Newton method to solve this? because I need to go through convolutions, etc... ? That's a real pitty. Have you got any other suggestion regarding how can I tackle this problem using fft and ifft ? Thanks a lot !